# Change Image src with fade effect on list menu hover

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create an effect where you hover over a link and the image in the backgound changes depending on which link was hovered.

```js
function changeImage(artistCover){
document.getElementById('slider').src = artistCover;
}
```

```css
a {
color:#ffffff;
}
a:hover {
color: orange;
}
.imgArea {
height:100vh; display:flex; justify-content:center; align-items:center;
}
.imgArea img {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: -1;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 object-fit: cover;
}

.imgArea:before {
content:"";
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
z-index:0;
}

ul li {
list-style-type: none; font-size: 24px;line-height: 2em;
font-variant: small-caps;font-weight: bold; text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="imgArea">
<img src="destinyschild.jpeg" id="slider">
<div style="position:absolute;">
<ul>
<li>
<a href="#" onmouseenter="changeImage('https://weareaddition.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/destinyschild.jpeg')">Destiny’s Child</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#" onmouseenter="changeImage('https://weareaddition.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/littlemix.jpeg')">Little Mix</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="" onmouseenter="changeImage('https://weareaddition.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/Pele.jpeg')">Pele</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#" onmouseenter="changeImage('https://weareaddition.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/chrisbrown.webp')">Chris Brown</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

The above code works and replaces the image without a fade effect. What do I need to add/modify to get the crosfade effect to work?

Here's a [JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/eduone/gps53zmt/134/) of my script as well. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Look into transitions at https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

Comment: Many thanks for your suggestion David, I've looked at css transitions and tried various things including css animations over the last 48 hours but still can't get it to crossfade the images. Please if you have any ideas that would be super helpful. I appreciate your help.